# Only getting one result when webscraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

having a problem with the below - whenever I run it it's only returning with the very first value for movieid and movie name. Was hoping to create something that'd take down every title and id on Netflix.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url ='https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/1365'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"nm-content-horizontal-row-item"})

for container in containers:
    
    title_container = container.findAll("a",{"class":"nm-collections-title nm-collections-link"})
    title_container = title_container[0].text

    movieid = container.findAll("a",{"class":"nm-collections-title nm-collections-link"})
    movieid = movieid[0].attrs['href']

print("Movie Name: " + title_container, "\n")
print("Movie ID: " , movieid, "\n")
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong

Answer (score 3):

You have to move your print statements into your loop so that they get printed with every iteration

```
for container in containers:
    
    title_container = container.findAll("a",{"class":"nm-collections-title nm-collections-link"})
    title_container = title_container[0].text

    movieid = container.findAll("a",{"class":"nm-collections-title nm-collections-link"})
    movieid = movieid[0].attrs['href']

    print("Movie Name: " + title_container, "\n") # move them in
    print("Movie ID: " , movieid, "\n")
```